# Declaring 'long' over 'int' in Java

Tags: java

If `int` is enough for a field, and if I use `long` for some reason, would that cost me more memory?

Comment: In what language and on what platform? This is fairly vague, and the answers will be compiler and platform-dependent (if you're asking about what I think you are).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the language. Java.

Comment: It's a really vague question, though. Without knowing what platform and language, it's hard to answer. The majority of the time, the small difference in memory is offset by faster CPU operations.

Comment: Also of note because long is 64 bit in Java, on a 32 bit machine, it is going to be assigned in 2 operations -- maybe of interest or not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, yes, a long is 8 bytes wide and an integer is 4 bytes wide. [This Java tutorial goes over the primitive data types.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) If you multiply the number of allocations by a certain amount (say, if you're allocating five million of these variables), the difference becomes more than negligible. For the average usage, however, it doesn't matter as much.

(You're already using Java, memory's kind of all over the place anyway.)

In native languages, there's a performance consideration; a 32-bit value can be held in a single register on a 32-bit architecture but not a 64-bit value; on 64-bit architectures, obviously, it can.  I'm not sure what kind of optimization Java does on its native integers, but this might be true in its runtime as well.  There's alignment issues to worry about, as well -- you see this more with using shorts and bytes, though.

Best practice would be to use the type you need.  If the value will never be over 2^31, don't use a long.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the speed thing applies equally to java as it does to native languages.

Comment: I am too. Just not 'sure sure'.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming from your previous questions that you mean to ask this in the scope of Java, the int data type is four bytes and the long data type is eight bytes.

However, whether the difference in size actually means a difference in memory usage depends on the situation.

If it's a local variable, it's allocated on the stack. As the stack is already allocated, using more stack space will not use more memory, provided of course that you don't exhaust the stack.

If it a member of a class, it will depend on how the members are aligned. Sometimes members are not stacked compactly in memory, but padding is used so that some members start at an even address. If you for example have a byte and an int in a class, there will likely be three bytes of padding between them so that the int starts at the next address divisible by four.

Answer (score 2):

`int`is 32 bit and `long` is 64 bit.  `long` takes twice as much memory (which is pretty insignificant for most applications).

Comment: On MS C/C++ compilers, long and int are the same size.

Comment: This is language compiler and platform dependent. It will always be 32 and 64 for both java and C# though.

Comment: Yep, and I've removed my -1 and previous comments.

Comment: *int is 32 bit and long is 64 bit* is true, but that does not necessarily imply that *long takes twice as much memory* because of alignements and padding issues.

Answer (score 2):

long in Java is 64bit, and int is 32bit, so obviously longs uses more memory (8 bytes instead of 4 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

ifwdev guessed correctly. Java defines an `int` as a 32-bit signed integer, and a `long` as a 64-bit signed integer. If you declare a variable as a `long`, then yes, it will take twice as much memory as the same variable declared as an `int`. In general, `int` is typically the "default" numeric type, even for values that could be contained in smaller types like a `short`. Unless you have a particular reason for requiring values greater than `2^31-1`, use an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> *...would that cost me more memory?*

You'll be using twice as memory

Before worrying about if you're using more memory or not, you should profile.

To use **1 megabyte** extra of ram using long rather than int you'll have to declare: **262,144** long variables (or use them indirectly in your program ).

So if for some reason you declare one or two long variables when int's should be used, you'll be using 4 or 8 bytes more of memory. Not too much to worry about ( I mean, there might be worst memory problems in your app )

Taken from the [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) here's the definition of int and long

> ***int***: The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of  -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). For integral values, this data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason (like the above) to choose something else. This data type will most likely be large enough for the numbers your program will use, but if you need a wider range of values, use long instead.
>
> ***long***: The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

But remember: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) according to  Donald Knuth  ( according to me Copy/Paste is the root of all evil though )

Answer (score 0):

If you know your data will fit in a specific data type (say `short int` in C), the only reason to use a bigger one is performance right? And if that's your goal, regardless of how marginal your performance gain is, as a general rule of thumb you want to use a size that matches your architecture's size (so for a normal 32-bit target system, you'd use a 32-bit type).

If you target more than one system, you can use a data type that matches the most often used one.